# Триггер для даты sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Попалась задачка, в которой нужно в которой нужно создать триггер, который при вводе записи в таблицу Оказание услуг заменяет значение null в поле Желаемая_дата на текущую дату.
Всё никак не могу правильно написать триггер,мой вариант вставляет дату только в новую запись, в то время, как мне нужно вставлять в текущую.
Формат поля ЖелаемаяДата - date.
Прошу указать на мои ошибки

```
    create trigger mytrig on ОказаниеУслуг
after insert
as 
begin
    insert into ОказаниеУслуг (ОказаниеУслуг.ЖелаемаяДата)
    values (GETDATE());
end
go
```

Comment: Это?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22594779/7753445

Comment: У вас after insert, а для существующей записи нужно after update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас `after insert`, а для существующей записи нужно `after update`